# Use regex to add empty groups

Tags: python, regex, empty-list

I'm a beginner python programmer. I'm trying to use a regular expression to build groups to append to a list. I'm not sure whether what I want to do can be covered with a single regex, or if I need to pass the text through more than one regex.

Test data:

yada yada 0.003 40 40.00

yadayada ya 55

yaaaaaaya 100.0000 4

My regex:

```
(\w+ *\w* *\w*) (\d*\.*\d*) *(\d*\.*\d*) *(\d*\.*\d*)\n
```

The groups that I get:

'yada yada','0.003','40','40.00'

'yadayada ya',**'55',empty,empty**

'yaaaaaaya',**'100.0000','4',empty**

BUT the groups that I want are:

'yada yada','0.003','40','40.00'

'yadayada ya',**empty,empty,'55'**

'yaaaaaaya',**empty,'100.0000','4'**

Is it possible to change the regex to introduce empty (\d*.*\d*) groups into those lines that have less than 3 of those groups? So that the number groups are "right-justified"?

I tried to add ? to the end of the first two (\d*) groups, but get the same empty groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to perform what you are colloquially describing as "right-justifying" the matches, i. e. prioritize the matching of later optional subexpressions, is to reverse the "greediness" of the optional components. In Python regex, this is accomplished by adding `?` to each quantified element:

```
(\w+ *\w* *\w*) (\d*?\.*?\d*?) *?(\d*?\.*?\d*?) *?(\d*?\.*?\d*?)\n
```

Note that your expression is quite liberal and will not validate certain poorly-formed input. If this works for you, great, otherwise you may want to consider sticking certain parts in optional groups, such as `(| \d+(?:\.\d+)?)` to lazily match a space and number, for example (the construct `(|x)` is equivalent to `((?:x)??)`).

Edit: As Tim pointed out, the shortcomings of this regex entail more than just permissiveness and could invoke catastrophic backtracking if the input is even slightly malformed. I'd recommend something a little more precise if you plan to stick with this method:

```
(\w+(?: \w+){0,2}) (|\d+(?:\.\d+)?) ?(|\d+(?:\.\d+)?) ?(|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\n
```

It can still match malformed input but at least it's a bit tighter now.

Comment: That doesn't change the regex' behavior of returning empty group matches at all, and it's just as prone to catastrophic backtracking as the original one.

Comment: @TimPietzcker It certainly does, please test it out before downvoting: https://regex101.com/r/dtKcH4/1 I agree the regex is sub-optimal, and mentioned as much. If you want to re-write it for him, do go ahead.

Comment: Of course I tested it. Just check your linked example - it does have the same problem (now the empty group is group 2 instead of group 4, but it's there just as well).

Comment: @TimPietzcker He says in his question that he *wants* those groups to be empty. Most likely he is approaching the problem in the wrong way, but that's not for me to decide. Let him experiment with different approaches, even if they are not ideal. Best way to learn. I personally prefer to answer users's questions without worrying too much about their coding habits.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. I should have read the question more carefully. I will retract my downvote, but my other comment still stands - add one non-digit character in the end, and the processing time increases by a factor of 1000 for your example string. (And if you add a space at the end, it changes the groups again. But feel free to lead him down the garden path :)

Comment: Well, it probably didn't help that I misunderstood your first comment :) And fortunately, this is a very pretty garden! The risk of inefficient/catastrophic backtracking is very real though and I should have realized that to begin with rather than being blasé about recommending only a slight modification to his regex. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thank you both for your time and expertise (and please forgive my inexperience). I will not be able to put either of these recommendations into practice in the next 12 hours but wanted to reply ASAP. I've tried the suggested regex test -- with the multi-line example it only gives one full match, and not 3 as expected. Likely though it is my misunderstanding that is the failure here.

Comment: @GJury You have to tweak a couple of options: add 'g' to make it continue matching past the first one, and then I'd also recommend 'm' to let `$` match the end of a line. Using `$` in your expression is better than `\n`, which may not match the last line if it isn't terminated by a line feed. Here you go: https://regex101.com/r/dtKcH4/3

Comment: Great work, thank you. Now: for me to study and understand it!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex has several problems, one of which is a high risk of [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) because there is an exponentially growing number of permutations that the regex engine needs to test in non-matching cases. Another problematic thing is that `\w` will also match digits, so the first group may contain numbers you didn't want it to contain.

Furthermore, for such a "dynamically growing" regex, you'd need a "match continuation" feature like the `\G` or `\K` anchors, but Python does not support those.

The best way would be to `.split()` the string into substrings, then check each substring if it contains a number (for example by `try`ing to convert it to a `float`) and behave accordingly.

Added bonus: You have a readable Python script instead of a very complicated regex.